# Python TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, data-structures, while-loop

I'm running this code in an attempt to assign key value pairs using a dict. to store the data (key = xvalue, yvalue) which is in two separate arrays. i.e.

```
1  def main():
2  path = 'some/path/'
3
4
5   d = {}
6   xcord = [1.2,2.4,2.9,3.0,4.1]
7   ycord = [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]
8   a=0
9   b=0
10  while b < 136 and a <= 21 :
11      for x in xcord and y in ycord :
12  -->    d{b}.append(xcord[x],ycord[y])
13         b=b+1
14         if a == 21:
15          a=0
16         else:
17          a=a+1
18  print(d)
19
20  if __name__ == "__main__":
21     main()
```

But when I run this I get a TypeError:

```
File "some/path/", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "some/path", line 12, in main
    for x in xcord and y in ycord :
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

I'm looking to append data from the xcord and ycord arrays to the dictionary and I'm clearly not doing this correctly.
I was thinking I could reference the dict for future calculations like this for example:

```
print(d{0})
# with a result
{1.2 , 1.0}
#   or  say I want to calculate slop between two points
sqrt((d{0, [1],[]} - d{2, [1],[]})sqrd + (d{0, [],[1]} - d{2, [], [1]})sqrd)
# with a result 
3.2
```

Please critique me on the Pythonic ways, I am new to Python. and any help is appreciated. I know the math portion is not correct as I was just show some syntax to help explain

Comment: is that `else` aligned with the `if` or the `for`?

Comment: You should use a consistent indentation amount. 4 is the usual, but 2 is somewhat acceptable (1 is not). Also don't call a variable `dict`, it hides the built in function of the same name.

Comment: @gilch You're correct, good eye. The else should be aligned properly with the if statement. Fixed.

Comment: @PaulRooney Thanks for the tips I'll make edits

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: `append(xcord[x],ycord[y])` is not legal. `append` takes only one argument. You may have intended to append a tuple which would be `append((x, y))` or you may wish to append both numbers into the list, which could be done as two append calls or using `extend([x, y])`,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
for x in xcord and y in ycord :
```

With:

```
for x,y in zip(xcord,ycord):
```

And lot more mistakes, so your code should be like this:

```
def main():
    path = 'some/path/'
    d = {}
    xcord = [1.2,2.4,2.9,3.0,4.1]
    ycord = [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]
    a=0
    b=0
    while b < 136 and a <= 21 :
        for x,y in zip(xcord,ycord):
           if b in d:
              d[b].append(x,y)
           else:
              d[b]=[x,y]
           b=b+1
           if a == 21:
              a=0
           else:
              a=a+1
    print(d)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Comment: To add to @U9-Forward's answer, the reason you were getting your `TypeError` is because Python interprets `x in xcord and y in ycord` as a Boolean expression; it will evaluate to `True` if `x` is in `xcord` and `y` is in `ycord` and will evaluate to `False` otherwise. It doesn't make sense to have a `for True:` or `for False:` statement, but you can iterate through a `zip` object since it has an `__iter__()` method,

Comment: @Joel Thank you for the insight on why the the error was present. This makes total sense to me now. I've been structuring my conditions incorrectly.

Comment: @user3600460 If you think that this post solved your question, consider accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark under the voting buttons for this post.

Comment: @U9-Forward this code works well except for the fact that my dictionary has doubled in intended size. The output length of the d {} should be 135 but it is returning 270. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for the support in my early python coding days.
The solution I found to work with what exactly I was expecting for the output was:

```
d = {}
b = 0
xcord = [1.2,2.4,2.9,3.0,4.1]
ycord = [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]

    for x,y in zip(xcord,ycord):
        if b in d:
            d[b].append(x,y)
        else:
            d[b] = [x,y]
        b=b+1
```